# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: www.metaverseswapping.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:metaverseswapping.com

Tags: wordpress, https

I am trying to solve this error from couple of days but no luck on my side.
I want all the URLs to point at https://metaverseswapping.com

Error
http://www.metaverseswapping.com
https://www.metaverseswapping.com

these links are not pointing at https://metaverseswapping.com

I have created the redirection rule, edited atacess file but it doesnt help google to identify the same, goolge is afaraid to send traffic to my side with this errors.

Technical Details
PHP- Wordpress
Server - Hostinger
Domain- godaddy
CDN - https://quic.cloud/

[httpstatus.io error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRgww.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this website is working totally fine.
Btw. If you are using managed WordPress hosting, most hosts will provide you with an automatic SSL Deployer tool.
In that case, a quick talk with your hosts' customer support will be resolve this conflict for you.

Btw, you shouldn't disclose the actual domain name. Please edit your question accordingly with [this example link.](https://example.com)

If not clear, let me know. If this helped, please mark this as an accepted answer.